# android studio : Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-beta1

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-beta1.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.0-beta1/gradle-2.3.0-beta1.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.0-beta1/gradle-2.3.0-beta1.jar
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.0-beta1/gradle-2.3.0-beta1.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.0-beta1/gradle-2.3.0-beta1.jar
Required by:
    project :

Answer (score 0):

`2.3.0-beta1` is really old build tools, latest stable is `2.3.3` and beta is `3.0.0-beta1`
Please search in project for `build.gradle` files and inside these files: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle...` and replace `2.3.0-beta1` with `2.3.3`

Final line must looks like `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'`.
When you still will have problems you will maybe need to upgrade gradle wrapper too: `./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 4.1` and run it twice. First time it will update gradle wrapper, second time it will download new gradle files.